# Print backwards all the positive even integers starting with 100 using loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

How do I print only the even integers using a loop?

so far I have:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
{
cout << i << ", ";
}
```

which prints all the numbers, even and odd. How do I print just the even numbers?

Comment: You add an if statement that checks whether i is even, and put the cout line inside of it.

Comment: `if (i % 2) { cout ...`

Comment: Instead of `i--`, which decreases `i` by 1, decrease `i` by 2.

Comment: Reopened. The claimed duplicate was about how to determine whether an integer is even or odd. That's not the only possible approach here. All that's needed is for the loop to count by 2 instead of 1; no checking needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh. All the comments (and the close vote) seem hung up on checking whether an integer is even. That's not needed; instead of skipping odd values, don't generate them in the first place:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 0; i-=2)
```